# Generating random strings until a given string is generated

Tags: python, string, if-statement, random

This is a program to generate some random string until the given string is generated. I can't get the idea of fixing the index in the `else` part .If the random generated character in the `attemptThis[i]` doesn't matches with the character in the `t[i]`, we are storing the character in the `attemptNext` right? And after that when it checks again, only one character is stored in the `attemptThis`?  I don't know whether or not i am asking the right way. I got the idea of statements in the `if` part. But the `else:attemptNext += t[i]` is confusing. An exp with example will be greatly appreciated. (code from gfg)

```
import string 
import random 
   
possibleCharacters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + 
                     string.ascii_uppercase + ' ., !?;:'
  
t = "geek"
  
attemptThis = ''.join(random.choice(possibleCharacters) 
                                for i in range(len(t))) 
attemptNext = '' 
  
completed = False
iteration = 0
  
while completed == False: 
    print(attemptThis) 
      
    attemptNext = '' 
    completed = True
      
    for i in range(len(t)): 
        if attemptThis[i] != t[i]: 
            completed = False
            attemptNext += random.choice(possibleCharacters) 
        else: 
            attemptNext += t[i] 
              
    iteration += 1
    attemptThis = attemptNext 
  
print("Target matched after " +
      str(iteration) + " iterations")
```

Comment: Is this some sort of brute force password breaker? The flow of the code is certainly very odd.

Comment: Could you please clarify what specific problem you're having trouble with and what result you're looking for? As the question is now, it's unclear what this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @EdericOytas I am extremely sorry. I have updated the question as per your needs.

Comment: @kingkupps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-match-string-random-strings-length/ - here is the link for your clarification.

Comment: No worries at all! Glad someone was able to help :) Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is building up a string for `attemptNext`. If a character in `attemptThis` is equal to its corresponding character in `t`, then that character is added to the end of `attemptNext`.

The code is weirdly written. In code, it's good practice to avoid `not` or `!=` in a simple expression in an `if-else` statement. In this case, it used `!=`. It's often better to use the opposite (`==`) and switch the bodies of each.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply. We are adding it to the end of the `attemptnext` . Then how can we fix the index of the character in the word?

Comment: In the `for` loop, the variable `i` is iterating from 0 through the length of `t` minus 1. Since accessing each character from start to end and iterating the same number of times, we are building `attemptNext` in order as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import random

s1 = input("enter the string:")
n = len(a)
s2 = None
char = string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase+string.ascii_lowercase

c = 1
while s1!=s2:
    s2= ''.join(random.choice(char) for i in range(n))
    c+=1
    print(c,s2)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string


possibleCharacters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + 
string.ascii_uppercase + ' ., !?;:'

a='zero'
c=1
while a != random:
      b = ''.join(random.choice(possibleCharacters)for i in range(len(a)))
      c=c+1
      print(b)
      if b ==a:
         print(a)
         print("target is matched after",c," attermpts")
         break
#try this short and simple
```